# What does mean by elements are skipped due to visible?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

In Clearcase UCM , I was trying to do inter-project delivery.

When delivery is about to be over, it shows some warning.

> 3 elements were skipped because they are not visible.  You should
>   determine why they are not visible before you complete this deliver or
>   rebase operation.  If these elements should be visible, cancel this
>   operation, fix the problem, and re-run the operation. 27 elements were
>   skipped because they are not visible.  You should determine why they
>   are not visible before you complete this deliver or rebase operation. 
>   If these elements should be visible, cancel this operation, fix the
>   problem, and re-run the operation.

What does that mean? Whether the file is not present is target stream or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a non-blocking warning, which means at the source branch level :

- a file has been modified since the last merge (so it is a candidate for the next merge, and will be part of the list of versions listed by ClearCase during said merge=
- it has since then deleted (rmname'd, that is unreferenced from its parent directory)

That means it is no longer visible from a source view.

For more, see technote "[Deliver or Rebase reports elements were skipped, because they are not visible](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21118911)":

> This message indicates that a `cleartool rmname` was performed on some version of the parent directory which is involved in a rebase or deliver operation.

See also "[About handling elements that are not visible](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/about_elements_not_visible.htm)"